# SQL : If first day of the new month then run report for previous month

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date

I have some reports which run showing data MTD

Here is the code that is not working how I would like

```
StartDate = select dateadd(s,0,dateadd(mm, datediff(m,0,getdate()),0))
EndDate = getdate()
```

Our data replication happens at the end of each day.
So on the First day of each month I don't want a blank report to run.

what I would like to happen.

Only If its the first day of the month then the **StartDate** must be beginning of last month and **EndDate** to be end of last month. Else use

```
StartDate = select dateadd(s,0,dateadd(mm, datediff(m,0,getdate()),0)) and 
EndDate = getdate()
```

Comment: Please give more information and what you have tried. Also you might want to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all.
so the rabbit hole got a bit deeper
Example : What about when the 1st falls on a Saturday ?

I need it to run using the last trading day if its the first day of the new month.

what I ended up using  was a function that uses our working hours table

```
ALTER FUNCTION [data].[Last_Trade_Day] (@Date date)
returns date as

begin
    declare @OrigDate date = isnull(@Date, getdate())
    return (
        select max(convert(date, wh_starttime))
        from Embrace.fact.Working_Hours
        where convert(date, wh_starttime) < @OrigDate
    )
end
```

The code in the report now look's like :

```
declare @EndDate date = Embrace.data.Last_Trade_Day(isnull(@Date, getdate()))
declare @StartDate date = dateadd(mm, 0, dateadd(mm, datediff(m, 0, @EndDate), 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure about your main query. This is how you could get first and last day of last month depending on the given date being 1st of current month.

Please note, else part of each case expression setting the current date for both first and last date. You can set them as `null` if needed.

```
DECLARE @Today DATETIME = GETDATE()

DECLARE @FirsDay DATETIME = CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, @Today) = 1 
                            THEN DATEADD(MONTH, -1, @Today) --first day of last month
                            ELSE @Today END --current date for other dates

DECLARE @LastDay DATETIME = CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, @Today) = 1 
                            THEN DATEADD(DAY, -1, @Today) --last date of last month
                            ELSE @Today END --current date for other dates
```

Comment: Thanks - Just used this on another report. I wanted to avoid joining on the Date Tables we have . Your Query Works Great. Would love to Vote your Post up but seems like it will take me years to earn enough rep Points - ha ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use something like this:

```
-- Create demo data
CREATE TABLE #dates(get_date_simulation datetime)

INSERT INTO #dates(get_date_simulation)
VALUES  (N'2015-07-01 13:46:47.063'), -- fallback to 2015-06-01
        (N'2015-07-02 13:46:47.063') -- use this date normal

-- Your part
SELECT  get_date_simulation, 
        CASE 
            WHEN DATEPART(day,get_date_simulation) = 1
            THEN DATEADD(month,-1,DATEADD(day,(DATEPART(day,get_date_simulation)-1)*-1,get_date_simulation))
            ELSE DATEADD(day,(DATEPART(day,get_date_simulation)-1)*-1, get_date_simulation)
        END as start_date, 
        CASE 
            WHEN DATEPART(day,get_date_simulation) = 1
            THEN DATEADD(second,-1,CONVERT(datetime,CONVERT(date,get_date_simulation)))
            ELSE get_date_simulation
        END as end_date
FROM #dates

-- Cleanup
DROP TABLE #dates
```

Which results into this:

```
get_date_simulation     start_date              end_date
----------------------- ----------------------- -----------------------
2015-07-01 13:46:47.063 2015-06-01 13:46:47.063 2015-06-30 23:59:59.000
2015-07-02 13:46:47.063 2015-07-01 13:46:47.063 2015-07-02 13:46:47.063
```

Comment: Thanks Much Appreciated - put me in the right direction. - See answer I ended up using.

Comment: Nice to hear. :-) Btw. I changed the start_date part, to go from the first instead from the date itself. :-) You can still remove the hours and so on by converting the start_date to date and back to datetime and it will start at 0 o'clock

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems as simple as subtracting 1 day from the current date to get the start date

```
SELECT StartDate =
    DATEADD(s,0,DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE() - 1),0))
```

Then you just get the end date using the current date without the time

```
SELECT EndDate =
    CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()
```

Then your query is `WHERE date >= StartDate and < EndDate`